# Why avoid string.ToLower() when doing case-insensitive string comparisons?

Tags: .net, string, performance, tolower

I have read that when in your application you do a lot of string comparison and using ToLower method, this method is quite costly. I was wondering of anyone could explain to me how is it costly. Would appreciate any info or explanation. Thanks!

Comment: Unless these are "significantly large" strings or they are of "innumerable quantity", this likely won't be a bottleneck .. ever. That being said, such normalization process - and especially in the case of in-memory strings - is a round-about way to describe the desired task. But such normalization is not always "bad", especially if the results are used [otherwise] anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's costly because a new string is "manufactured".

Compare that to calling, say, Equals with an overload that asks for a case-insensitive comparison. This allows the comparison to terminate, without having to create a new string, as soon as a mismatch is identified.

Answer (score 11):

See also [writing culture-safe managed code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms994325.aspx) for a very good reason why not to use `ToLower()`.

In particular, see the section on the Turkish "I" - it's caused no end of problems in the past where I work...

Calling `"I".ToLower()` won't return `"i"` if the current culture is Turkish or Azerbaijani. Doing a direct comparison on that will cause problems.

Answer (score 10):

There is another advantage to using the [String.Compare(String, String, StringComparison)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6883c06(v=vs.110).aspx) method, besides those mentioned in the other answers:

You can pass `null` values and still get a relative comparison value. That makes it a whole lot easier to write your string comparisons.

```
String.Compare(null, "some StrinG", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

From the documentation:

> One or both comparands can be **null**. By definition, any string, including the empty string (""), compares greater than a null reference; and two null references compare equal to each other.

Comment: can I do the same with String.StartsWith()?

Comment: @ElenaDBA No. According to the documentation `string.StartsWith()` will throw for a `null` argument. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Actually what I mean iif I use StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase as an argument String.StartsWith(), will it improve the performance?

Comment: @ElenaDBA what do you mean? would you like to call `StartsWith()` first before calling `Compare()`? string `Compare()` is a 'smart' method, it will stop comparing after the first mismatch. -- I wouldn't be so concerned about performance, unless you have an actual performance problem. And when you do, use a profiler to find the actual bottleneck. I think you will find it is not were you will think it is.

Answer (score 3):

Each time you call ToLower(), a new copy of the string will be created (as opposed to making the case changes in-place). This can be costly if you have many strings or long strings.

From [String.ToLower](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolower.aspx) docs:

> Returns a copy of this string converted to lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

As somebody already answered, ToLower() will create a new string object, which is extra cost comparing to using "IgonoreCase". If this ToLower is triggered frequently, you end up creating a lot of small objects in your heap, and will add Garbage Collection time, which becomes a performance penalty.