# C# check windows Service status

Tags: windows-services

I'm using the following code to check my windows service status:

```
 ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("service name", "service location");
```

in the service location H'm putting the server name which my service reside on.
on my test environment, I have the service and portal (IIS) where I check my service on the same server and it works fine, but on my production environment, The service is on a different server than my portal IIS.

and my code is unable to check the status. I'm sure it is a permission issue, but I tried so many this to make it work but no use.

my question is: what "type of permission" to be given to what "user" or "machine name"?  please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all anyway, I have used another way through WMI and it worked:

```
ConnectionOptions op = new ConnectionOptions();
op.Username = "";
op.Password = "";
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(SVClocation+@"\root\cimv2", op);
scope.Connect();
ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath("Win32_Service");
ManagementClass services = new ManagementClass(scope, path, null);
foreach (ManagementObject service in services.GetInstances())
{
    if (service.GetPropertyValue("Name").ToString().ToLower().Equals("serviceName"))
    {
        if (service.GetPropertyValue("State").ToString().ToLower().Equals("running"))
        {
            //do something
        }
        else
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See [Why avoid string.ToLower() when doing case-insensitive string comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28440783/1364007)

Answer (score 0):

Does your IIS portal impersonate? It seems it does. As such you are falling into [Kerberos constrained delegation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj553400.aspx) ('two-hop'). You cannot 'fix' this. You have to ask a domain administrator to enable and configure constrained delegation for your IIS application.

An alternative is *not* to impersonate in your IIS. In this case you need grant appropriate permissions to your portal app pool. The required permission in [`SC_MANAGER_CONNECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685981%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Read more at [KB179249: Access to the Service Control Manager](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179249). Obviously the app-pool must be a domain account and the IIS and target service host machine should be in the same domain, or in domains that have a trust relationship.